# XSS - Bypass this RegExp

Tags: xss

How could this anti-xss regexp be bypassed: `/<(?:\w+)\W+?[\w]/`

I am working on it but I can't find a way.

Just to be sure that I have understood it correctly, this regexp search for a pattern with a '<', then one or more characters, then one or more non character and then a character.

Right?

EDIT:
Here is the code:

```
<?php
$xss = $_POST['xss']; 

if (preg_match('/<(?:\w+)\W+?[\w]/', $xss)) {
     echo '<p>I don\'t think so</p>'; 
} else {
    echo $xss; 
}
```

Comment: If you're not doing a global replace, one could simply use a 2nd tag.

Comment: have you tried regex parsers? http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws?regex=%3C%28%3F%3A%5Cw+%29%5CW+%3F%5B%5Cw%5D&env=env_java

Comment: For regexes, I love using: http://regex101.com/

Answer (score 8):

It really depends on how you use this regex. I'll use PHP code as an example:

**Unsafe Example: Replace**

```
echo "replaced: " . preg_replace('/<(?:\w+)\W+?[\w]/', '', $_GET['input']);
```

This would not be safe. Example:

```
input=<<a|ascript>alert('xss');</script>
```

This is because your regex does what you think it does: it searches for `<` followed by one or more alphanumeric character, followed by one or more non-alphanumeric characters, and then a single alphanumeric character.

So in the above attack string, `<a|a` (another example for clarity: `<aaa|||z`) matches exactly this and will be removed. Thus, the remaining string is `<script>...`.

**Safer Example: Filter**

If on the other hand you use it like this:

```
$isAttack = preg_match('/<(?:\w+)\W+?[\w]/', $_GET['input']);
if (!$isAttack) { echo "filtered: " . $_GET['input']; }
```

The above would not work.

**Safer Example: Weaknesses**

You should still be careful where you output user input, even if you use the regex like in the safer example. This for example would not be safe:

```
$isAttack = preg_match('/<(?:\w+)\W+?[\w]/', $_GET['input']);
if (!$isAttack) { echo "link: <a href="' . " . $_GET['input'] . '">click me</a>'; }
```

Example attack:

```
input=" onmouseover="alert('xss')
```

For more places where this kind of filtering is not good enough, see the owasp [XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: See the Edit in my first post